# Should an IFR-certified radio's automated nav aid identification feature be considered positive identification?

Tags: navigation, avionics

Should an IFR-certified radio's automated nav aid identification feature be considered positive identification? Should manual identification still be performed? Does anyone know if this is addressed in any FAA regulation or publication?

An example of automated identification is found on the Garmin 430. When a nav aid is tuned automated identification takes place and the result is annunciated visually.

Comment: This strikes me as a very odd question. If the G430 is FAA certified, then I would think that it would have been determined to be trustworthy through a long and expensive process. Of course, the FAA is staffed by people, and people can (and do) make mistakes. Is there something that leads you to believe that it isn't trustworthy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has been discussed a couple of times on the AOPA forums (members only) and the conclusion there was that it's completely fine to trust the automated identification. If the system is fully certified for IFR then why wouldn't you trust it? And if you don't trust one specific feature then why should you trust any of them?

Identifying NAVAIDs correctly is in the [instrument PTS](https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/test_standards/media/faa-s-8081-4e.pdf) but the FAA doesn't require any specific method of checking. In my last instrument checkride I used a G1000 and the DPE had no problem with me using the automatic identification; that's what it's there for.

Having said all that, things can and do go wrong, so cross-checking against other sources is still a good idea. For example, when you load a VOR approach from the database, the G1000 will automatically tune NAV1 to the NAVAID frequency and identify it. If either the frequency or the name doesn't match what's on the approach plate - or if the name is missing because it couldn't be identified - then something is wrong and you need to investigate.

Ultimately I think this is a question of comfort level, both personally and with the equipment. Some people will check the morse ID directly every time, out of habit or preference. Others won't, because they're confident that they know the equipment well enough not only to trust it, but also to identify and handle any problems.

Comment: Awesome answer. I really appreciate that you also had the personal experience of using automated nav aid identification during a check ride. Thanks!

Comment: I always ID by audio because I love morse code

Answer (score 1):

I've wondered the same thing with the Garmin G1000 glass cockpit as it has the same functionality as the 430 - it processes the audio morse code signal usually filtered using the ID button on a regular NAVCOM to see if the character code is present. It cannot, however, process a non-morse audio identifier such as a recorded voice and you'll have to listen if it doesn't identify and display the NAVAID's 3-letter identifier automatically. Published recommendations for positive navaid identification are in the FAA Pilot's Handbook of Aeronautical Knowledge Chapter 15, page 23 [Link Here](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/pilot_handbook/media/PHAK%20-%20Chapter%2015.pdf), and I'm certain in some other places as well (probably the FAA AIM). I will certainly be listening to the morse code just to verify - when flying IFR in IMC (instrument meteorological conditions) your life is on the line. If it's a clear VFR day and you know the route and you definitely know where you are and you're using the NAVAID just for reference to keep a straight course, then maybe not, but in any other situation I'd be listening and checking the morse code or voice recording against my sectional/chart.